# Enviar email com PHPMailer sem autenticação?

Tags: php, envio-de-email

Estou usando o seguinte código para enviar email:

```
<?php
require 'libs/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mailer = new PHPMailer();

$mailer ->isSMTP();
$mailer ->isHTML(true);
$mailer->CharSet = "UTF-8";

$mailer->SMTPAuth = true;
$mailer->SMTPSecure = "tls";
$mailer->Host = "smtp.live.com";
$mailer->Port = 587;
$mailer->Username = "leonardo-s@outlook.com";
$mailer->Password = "*********";

$mailer->From = "leonardo-s@outlook.com";
$mailer->FromName = "leonardo vialrinho";

$mailer->Subject = "TESTE DE EMAIL";
$mailer->Body = "body HTML";
$mailer->AltBody = "body texto";

$mailer->addAddress("leonardo-i@outlook.com");

if($mailer -> send()) {
    echo "Enviado";
} else {
    echo "Erro: ".$mailer->ErrorInfo;
}
?>
```

Até aí sem problema, mas como seria em um formulário de contato? Onde o usuário não vai informar a senha do `email` dele. E também não acho legal nem pra mim mesmo colocar a senha do meu `email` no código (em caso que fosse enviar uma confirmação de registro, etc)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Formulário de contato é você enviando uma mensagem para você mesmo, não é a pessoa enviando a mensagem para você. Não precisa contatar o servidor dela para fazer isto, precisa da sua senha.

É assim mesmo que funciona, ou coloca no código ou coloca em arquivo de configuração, o que acaba dando na mesma. O que dá para fazer é criptografar a informação, quase ninguém faz isto em PHP.

Tem soluções para evitar colocar a senha na aplicação, mas é complexa e não costuma compensar o trabalho, então todo mundo faz assim. De qualquer forma teria alguma proteção em algum lugar.

Formulário de confirmação é outra coisa, mas o processo é o mesmo. É você enviando a mensagem para outra pessoa, precisa da sua senha.

Sempre que abre um formulário na web está abrindo a possibilidade de ataques e existem técnicas sofisticadas para prevenir isto. Como esses ataques não costumam trazer vantagens é raro alguém fazer o ataque. E por isso é mais raro ainda alguém se prevenir contra isto.

Só tome o cuidado para não dar a chance de um formulário poder ao mesmo tempo permitir para a pessoa escolher a mensagem que será enviada e para quem a mensagem será enviada. Isso permite o envio de *spam* pela sua conta. Este é um ataque que traz vantagens.

O que não pode fazer em hipótese alguma é usar um servidor de e-mail que não precisa de autenticação para envio de mensagens.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).